# Laptop CPU performance problem

Tags: 20.04, performance, cpu-load

I have a new and powerful Dell laptop (Prevision 5540). It's almost idle, CPU is not much used (less then 10%), but the fans are constantly working. psensor also shows unnatural spikes. I don't even know where to looks at for this kind of problem.

I tried disabling nvidia, using intel (power saving mode) in the NVIDIA profiles. Didn't change anything.

```
 OS: Ubuntu 20.04 focal
 Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.4.0-33-generic
 DE: GNOME 3.36.2
 WM: Mutter
 Disk: 108G / 934G (13%)
 CPU: Intel Core i9-9880H @ 16x 4.8GHz [88.0°C]
 GPU: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile) (rev 02)
 RAM: 20998MiB / 31742MiB
```

[image]

```
top - 10:14:03 up 4 days, 30 min,  1 user,  load average: 4.35, 4.46, 4.35
Tasks: 470 total,   1 running, 469 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1.2 us,  0.9 sy,  0.2 ni, 97.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.7 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  31742.2 total,   2238.1 free,  15806.6 used,  13697.5 buff/cache
MiB Swap:    976.0 total,    513.9 free,    462.1 used.  12656.7 avail Mem
```

-

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           30Gi        15Gi       2.2Gi       2.8Gi        13Gi        12Gi
Swap:         975Mi       462Mi       513Mi
```

Comment: When the fans are running what's the CPU temperature?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `top`.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix All the temperatures can be seen in the psensor screenshot. Basically fans never stopped during the whole time.

Comment: @rosencreuz Ah yes I see that now on my computer. I didn't yesterday on my phone. You can try disabling turbo boost and setting max frequency lower but that is more of a band-aid.

Comment: As a matter of fact, disabling the turbo boost calmed down the cpu, everything seems fien after that. But what is the impact of it?